# Use two textboxes to filter a listbox

Tags: excel, vba, search, filter, listbox

I am doing a live filter on a listbox and am trying to add another textbox to the filter.

I have one textbox, `StoreBox`. When I type in a number to search for in Row C it returns 8 columns from that row. I have that working.

But I need to add a search date. I need to be able to search for the Store Number and the Date seperately or together. So it will return if both are in the row... or if I just type in one, it will return for the one criterium.

So `Storebox` and `DateBox` are the textboxes that I filter on. Below is the code I'm using, but everything I've tried doesn't work; I can't get the second one to work.

Does anyone know how I can alter the code to get this to work?

```
Private Sub StoreBox_Change()
    Sheets("Data").Activate
    Dim rw
    Dim strText As String

    strText = LCase(StoreBox.Text)
    dateText = LCase(DateBox.Text)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("C9:C5000")
    With ResultsBox
        .RowSource = ""
        .ColumnCount = 8
        For Each rw In rng.Rows
            If InStr(LCase(Cells(rw.Row, 3)), strText) Or InStr(LCase(Cells(rw.Row, 3)), strText) Then
                .AddItem Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value
                .List(ResultsBox.ListCount - 1, 0) = Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value
                .List(ResultsBox.ListCount - 1, 1) = Cells(rw.Row, 3).Value
                .List(ResultsBox.ListCount - 1, 2) = Cells(rw.Row, 4).Value
                .List(ResultsBox.ListCount - 1, 3) = Cells(rw.Row, 5).Value
                .List(ResultsBox.ListCount - 1, 4) = Cells(rw.Row, 6).Value
                .List(ResultsBox.ListCount - 1, 5) = Cells(rw.Row, 7).Value
                .List(ResultsBox.ListCount - 1, 7) = Cells(rw.Row, 9).Value
            End If
```

Comment: Both textboxes are filtering column 3.

Comment: Sorry the second box is filtering column 5

Answer (score 0):

Since the `DateBox.Text` should be filtering column 5 then this should fix the problem:

> ```
> If InStr(LCase(Cells(rw.Row, 3)), strText) Or InStr(LCase(Cells(rw.Row, 5)), dateText) Then
> ```

I would prefer to use `Instr`'s compare parameter over `LCase()`

> ```
> If InStr(1, Cells(rw.Row, 3).Value, strText, vbTextCompare) Or InStr(1, Cells(rw.Row, 5).Value, dateText, vbTextCompare) Then
> ```